# How can I set the images like the link image below in vuetify?

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I want to quantify my `v-img` like the one you see in the image below.

[image: link to example image]

Is there a way to make something like the image you see with vuetify's `v-img`.

```
 <div class="row">
      <v-img style="margin:2px" max-height="301" max-width="380"
      :key="index" v-for="(image, index) in post.userPostImg" 

      :src="$store.state.baseURL + '/news/' + image"> </v-img>
    </div>
```

Comment: you could use grid or flex to define areas for your image and then use v-img in each area to render the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two rows with `no-gutters` prop, the first one contains one image and the other one contains three columns that conain the 3 images :

```
  <v-row no-gutters>
      <v-col cols="12">
        <v-img :src="`https://picsum.photos/500/300?image=51`" aspect-ratio="1">

        </v-img>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <v-row no-gutters>
      <v-col cols="4">
        <v-img :src="`https://picsum.photos/500/300?image=52`" aspect-ratio="1">

        </v-img>
      </v-col>
      <v-col cols="4">
        <v-img :src="`https://picsum.photos/500/300?image=53`" aspect-ratio="1">

        </v-img>

      </v-col>
      <v-col cols="4">
        <v-img :src="`https://picsum.photos/500/300?image=54`" aspect-ratio="1">

        </v-img>

      </v-col>

    </v-row>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/abmBmdz)**